# Version 12 Documentation bugs

Tags: documentation, version-12

Not a question but would like to ask if anyone else has installed version 12 of the wolfram language and found links missing or pointing in the wrong direction on the guide pages. For example,

- on `guide/NeuralNetworks`, `LearnDistribution` - automatic learning of data distribution. The `LearnDistribution` is not hyperlinked to its function page. While on the cloud, the reference page is properly linked.
- on the same page under `Importing & Exporting`, `Import` is recognized as a `Front End Token` rather than a `Function`.

I would like to confirm if this is the case with my installation or a bug. Can someone who has version 12 installed please check. There were other cases but I can't remember them right now (will add them as I re-encounter or remember them).

Comment: I can confirm both of these issues in my Linux installation of version 12.

Comment: For something like this, you should go to the Help menu and select "Give Feedback".  If it is reproducible (which this definitely is), then a bug report will be filed and tracked. Not to discourage posting questions here, but for obvious bugs like this you should make sure to also fill out the feedback form.

Comment: Same errors in Mac version of Mathematica 12 (hardly surprising that these link errors would be platform-independent).

Comment: I don't have V12, but there are similar documentation errors in V11.3. The bad `Import` link also occurs in V11.3. When a symbol that should be a link in not a link, simply copy and paste it into the search field at the top of the documentation window. By all means report your findings to WRI; the more reports they receive, the more likely the problem will be corrected.

Comment: You can also go to the online version of the doc page (use the URL dropdown on the top right), scroll to the bottom, and use the Give Feedback link. I second what Jason said: if it's an obvious bug, report to Wolfram directly!

Comment: If you file a report, please add a header telling others so. I don’t want to waste my time having to raise report numbers so bugs get fixed! See [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2317/764). Needless to say: I am all for public bug and case reports here and vote to reopen this.